# Is it right to say "It does do it"?

Tags: grammaticality

To stress the tendency / capability of one performing an action, perhaps with a touch of surprising factor, I could say "I do do it", for example:

> I do speak 3 languages.

When it comes to third person singular, and when the action was mentioned previously in the context thus can be replaced with "it", is it correct to say

> It does do it.

The above sentence doesn't feel right hence the question... Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's called "emphatic _do_", and it requires extra stress. Like all other instances of _do_, if it's followed by a complement clause, the verb in it must be an infinitive. There's nothing wrong with the example sentence; it just requires a context to be understood.

Comment: I included the word ***definitely*** in my Google Books search for [*(someone / something definitely **does do** that*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22definitely+does+do+that%22) to make it obvious that most / all returned results are in fact *emphatic*.

Comment: The problem with your second sentence is not really grammatical. The repetition of "do" feels strange, and the vagueness of "do it" makes it unclear. Emphatic do is usually followed by something more specific.

Comment: As @JohnLawler says, it would be fine with context. Person1: *This robot should do your homework.* Person 2: *It **does** do it!* [This robot **does** do my homework!]

Comment: @John I understood that *complements* were required elements. As "It does" is correct on its own, that means "do it" is not a required element, so not a complement. Am I wrong about that?

Comment: @gotube — *It does* is answer ellipsis for *It does do it*. The complement is understood.

Comment: @gotube That's a different usage of the term _complement_. I use it the same way as McCawley; a complement is a clause that's used as a noun argument of some predicate.  [There are 4 main types in English.](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/complements.pdf)